# Audio through VGA?

Tags: windows-7, vga, s-video, rca

How can I get my video card / VGA port to output sound?

I want to plug the red, white and yellow RCA plugs into my RCA monitor (it has built in speakers).

[image: vga to s-vid and audio]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

VGA is video only. I can't possibly think of any use for the pictured adapter, except possibly with some non-standard specialty equipment that sends signals on pins where they shouldn't be.

[For specificity's sake](http://pinouts.ru/Video/VGA15.shtml):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Video cards don't emit audio.  Video cards and audio cards can combine their efforts and send everything to a HDMI port, but each looks after it's own media.

You most likely want this pair of cables:

[image: VGA to RCA] [image: 2.5mm to RCA]

Comment: This isn't exactly true - lots of new video cards have onboard audio controllers for, say, output over HDMI or DP.  (Of course, this assumes a video protocol *that supports carrying audio on the same cable*, and of course VGA is not one.)

Comment: Thanks for that! I suspected technology would have gotten ahead of me.